# Upload any file cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i can only upload files like .jpg and .png and i want to upload .zip, .psd, .ai, etc, but when i try i get an error

> Notice (8): Undefined index: url [APP/Controller\MultimediaController.php, line 70]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined index: url [APP/Controller\MultimediaController.php, line 71]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined index: url [APP/Controller\MultimediaController.php, line 72]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined index: url [APP/Controller\MultimediaController.php, line 75]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined index: url [APP/Controller\MultimediaController.php, line 81]

My MultimediaControler:

```
    public function add()
{
    $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->patchEntity($multimedia, $this->request->data);

          // Saving the file
        $file = $_FILES['url']; //Line 70
        $path = "webroot\\files\\" .$_FILES['url']['name'];   //Line 71
        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['url']['tmp_name'], $path);  //Line 72


        $filename = $_FILES['url']['name'];  //Line 75

        $created = $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'];

        $type = mime_content_type($path);

        $size =  $_FILES['url']['size'];   //Line 81

        $multimedia->set('mime_type', $type);
        $multimedia->set('url', $filename);
        $multimedia->set('filename', $filename);
        $multimedia->set('size', $size);
        $multimedia->set('created_by', $created);



        if ($this->Multimedia->save($multimedia)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The multimedia has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The multimedia could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $languages = $this->Multimedia->Languages->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $categories = $this->Multimedia->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $users = $this->Multimedia->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('multimedia', 'languages', 'categories', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);
}
```

**Update**

if i try to upload a psd file and print $multimedia i get this:

> { "mime_type": "directory", "url": null, "filename": null, "size": null, "created_by": 3 }

but if i upload a jpg or png i get all the data

Comment: What is `Multimedia` - seems like a custom component or helper class? Please post that class source code as well.

Comment: "Multimedia" is my table database